# How to pass a value along with p:commandButton with p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dialog which is contains two listboxes, one checkbox and one button. I try to pass values of these components to backing bean.

```
<p:dialog header="Add" widgetVar="dlgAdd" resizable="false"
                id="dlgAddId" showEffect="fade" modal="true">
                <h:form id="dlgAddForm">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                        <p:outputLabel>Name*</p:outputLabel>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="addname" value="#{notificationsSettingManagedBean.customerUserEmailSetting.userNameSurname}" effect="fold">                            
                            <f:selectItems value="#{notificationsSettingManagedBean.customerUserNameSurnameList}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:outputLabel>Email-ID*</p:outputLabel>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="addsurname" value=""  effect="fold">                           
                            <f:selectItems value="#{notificationsSettingManagedBean.customerUserEmailsList}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                    </p:panelGrid>              

                    <p:panel>
                        <div align="center">
                            <p:outputLabel>Email Notifications</p:outputLabel>
                        </div>                      
                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">

                        <p:outputLabel>Order Submitted</p:outputLabel>
                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{notificationsSettingManagedBean.customerUserEmailSetting.orderSubmit}"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>



                    <div align="center">
                        <p:commandButton
                                actionListener="#{notificationsSettingManagedBean.saveCustomerEmailSettings}"
                                immediate="true" value="Save" ajax="true"
                                oncomplete="dlgAddId.hide();" />
                    </div>

                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
```

On notificationsSettingManagedBean, i create customerUserEmailSetting object which is contains get and set methods of userNameSurname,customerUserEmailsList and ordersubmit.

Problem is when try to get this data on saveCustomerEmailSettings method on backing bean i see that these data are null. How can i pass them to backing bean?

Comment: Remove immediate=true on your commandButton

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked fine.